# How can I ensure drafts are not included in my gmail filters?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have created some filters in Gmail.  Some of the results include drafts.  This drives me nuts.

How can I create a filter with the requirement that drafts be excluded?

I've tried putting the search criteria along with

> -in:draft

in the gmail search box, and clicking the down arrow to use the filter creation shortcut, but when I add

> -in:draft

the "continue" link is grayed out, meaning I can't create a filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

Filters act on incoming messages, so there is no need to include -in:drafts.

## Explanation

> I have created some filters in Gmail. Some of the results include drafts. This drives me nuts.

Actually what you are seeing is the search results of applying the filter search criteria to your mailbox.

From [Create rules to filter your emails](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en)

> You can manage your incoming mail using Gmail’s filters to send email to a label, or archive, delete, star, or automatically forward your mail.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't understand how to prevent all those drafts from showing up in my filter.  (Not sure if this is relevant to my question, but note that I have successfully made filters to select messages sent by me to a specific address or domain.)

Comment: @aparente001 : It looks to me that you are confused about the filters purpose and workings but maybe I'm wrong. Please edit your question to describe how are you using your filters after they are created.

Comment: Rubén - Some filters are based on a phrase in the "from" field, some in the "subject," some in the body.  The gmail filter becomes a folder in Thunderbird.  When I look at the contents of the folder, all my drafts that meet the filter criteria are listed.  Each additional draft which is autosaved every so often shows up.  I would prefer to see the drafts listed only if I specifically visit "Drafts."  I hope that is clearer.

Comment: The Gmail filter becoming a folder in Thunderbird isn't a Gmail built-in feature , and it's not a POP / IMAP feature either. I think that you should ask on [su] about that Thunderbird's folders.